# Create view with computed column using a where clause

Tags: sql

I want to add a computed column to a view, by performing a simple math operation on  a column where the value of a corresponding column is a certain value. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW v_tracks 
AS 
SELECT
    (trackid + 1) as calcTrackId Where name like "WuTang",
    tracks.name,
    albums.Title AS album,
    media_types.Name AS media,
    genres.Name AS genres
FROM
    tracks
INNER JOIN albums ON Albums.AlbumId = tracks.AlbumId
INNER JOIN media_types ON media_types.MediaTypeId = tracks.MediaTypeId
INNER JOIN genres ON genres.GenreId = tracks.GenreId;
```

However, this doesn't work. I only want the track ID incremented by one when the name (referring to the `name` column in the view) is "WuTang". How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you dont have SQL technology listed not sure, but this should work (or similar syntax depending on technology)

```
CREATE VIEW v_tracks 
AS 
SELECT
    CASE WHEN name LIKE 'WuTang' THEN trackid + 1 ELSE trackid END AS calcTrackId,
    tracks.name,
    albums.Title AS album,
    media_types.Name AS media,
    genres.Name AS genres
FROM
    tracks
INNER JOIN albums ON Albums.AlbumId = tracks.AlbumId
INNER JOIN media_types ON media_types.MediaTypeId = tracks.MediaTypeId
INNER JOIN genres ON genres.GenreId = tracks.GenreId;
```

Comment: This works great. One thing I noticed is the new calculated column does not have an associated type while all other columns in the view do. Is there a way to force it to use a type?

Comment: cast it :  cast(calculatedcol as datatype)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
(case when name = 'WuTang'
      then row_number() over (partition by name order by ?)
 end) as calcTrackId
```

The `?` should correspond to the ordering that you care about.  You can always use `name` if you don't care.

This will assign an incremental value to each WuTang track and `NULL` to others.

If you want the incremental value to be on all rows, not just the WuTang rows, then use a cumulative sum:

```
sum(case when name = 'WuTang' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by ?) as calcTrackId
```